# mysql sum/total a field of only most recent records with left joins

Tags: mysql, sum

```
select *
from (
SELECT contracts.*, customers.Manager2
FROM contracts
LEFT JOIN customers ON contracts.CID = customers.CID
WHERE contracts.Status = Active AND contracts.Effective_Date <= NOW() AND customers.Manager2 = 'person2'
ORDER BY contracts.Contract_ID DESC
) x 
group by CID
```

I have two tables, one for customer data, which includes an assigned account manager, and one for speocific contract data for those customers.  The customers can have more than one contract record for historic purposes, and the most current one is the most active contract or addendum. Within the contract table is a field of number of units, which can vary by contract. The dates on the contracts can vary and are not uniform, so some may be 2 years old, while some are only 1.

I am trying to run a query to sum/total up the total amount of units an account manager is assigned, pulling the number of units from only the most recent contract for the customers they are assigned to.

I have a query below that is used already to pull a report of all the most CURRENT contracts, and have been able to SUM ALL contracts, but can't seem to figure out how to SUM only the most CURRENT contracts for that particular manager.

customers

| CID | Status | Manager2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Active | person1 |
| 222 | Active | person2 |
| 333 | Active | person2 |
| 444 | Active | person3 |

contracts

| Contract_ID | CID | Effective_Date | Number_of_Units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 523 | 111 | 2022-01-01 | 85 |
| 100 | 111 | 2020-01-01 | 85 |
| 423 | 222 | 2022-01-01 | 1235 |
| 500 | 333 | 2022-01-01 | 652 |
| 153 | 333 | 2010-01-01 | 652 |
| 523 | 444 | 2022-01-01 | 700 |

Results should be:

```
person1 85
person2 1887
person3 700
```